# Issue with ASCii in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

I am trying to convert a string of varchar to ascii. Then i'm trying to make it so any number that's not 3 digits has a 0 in front of it. then i'm trying to add a 1 to the very beginning of the string and  then i'm trying to make it a large number that I can apply math to it.

I've tried a lot of different coding techniques. The closest I've gotten is below:

```
s = 'Ak'
for c in s:
    mgk = (''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in s))
    num = [mgk]

var = 1
num.insert(0, var)
mgc = lambda num: int(''.join(str(i) for i in num))
num = mgc(num)
print(num)
```

With this code I get the output: 165107

It's almost doing exactly what I need to do but it's taking out the 0 from the ord(A) which is 65. I want it to be 165. everything else seems to be working great. I'm using '%03d'% to insert the 0.

How I want it to work is:

Get the ord() value from a string of numbers and letters.

if the ord() value is less than 100 (ex: A = 65, add a 0 to make it a 3 digit number)

take the ord() values and combine them into 1 number. 0 needs to stay in from of 65. then add a one to the list. so basically the output will look like:

1065107

I want to make sure I can take that number and apply math to it.

I have this code too:

```
s = 'Ak'
for c in s:
    s = ord(c)
    s = '%03d'%s
    mgk = (''.join(str(s)))
    s = [mgk]
    var = 1
    s.insert(0, var)
    mgc = lambda s: int(''.join(str(i) for i in s))
    s = mgc(s)
    print(s)
```

but then it counts each letter as its own element and it will not combine them and I only want the one in front of the very first number.

When the number is converted to an integer, it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? I am kinda confused:

```
a = 'Ak'
result = '1' + ''.join(str(f'{ord(char):03d}') for char in a)
print(result) # 1065107
# to make it a number just do:
my_int = int(result)
```

Comment: kind of. I know it sounds confusing. I wanna take a string or numbers and letters, convert it to ord(), add 0 to the beginning of any ord value that is less than 100, than add a 1 to the very beginning of the string then convert that string to an interger without it remove the 0's from and ord value that's less than 100.

Comment: Thats exactly what the above does.

Comment: When I ran it, the output bad a b but I probably fat fingered something. I'll run it again.